# Import data from text file into PostgreSQL. "Postgres_Copy" Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, import, rails-postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL with ruby and rails app and have `Postgres_copy` gem installed
https://github.com/diogob/postgres-copy

I have hotels table and want to import text file using function `pg_copy_from` the gem. Data in the file is separated by the "|" symbol.

So I have created rake task

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :import do
    desc "Copy hotels records to the database"
    task :hotels => :environment do
      Hotel.pg_copy_from 'db/ActivePropertyList.txt', :delimiter => '|', :map => {
        'HotelID' => 'ean_hotel_id',
        'SequenceNumber' => 'sequence_number',
        'Name' => 'name',
        'Address' => 'address'}
    end
  end
end
```

If i run `rake db:import:hotels` nothing happens. What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that when I run `psql` and try to see all realtions by `\d` command, it says "No relations found."

However, I ran `rake:db:create:all` and `rake db:migrate` commands and can see the schema file. Also, `\l` command in psql console shows my database.

Maybe it would be easier just to run

```
c = Hotel.connection.raw_connection
c.exec(%q{\copy hotels (hotel_id, name) FROM 'db/ActivePropertyList.txt' DELIMITER '|'})
```

, but I suggest nothing happens because of the missing relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My import failed because of the upper-case issue that is common for the PostgreSQL. Renaming all header fields and database column names to lower case did the trick.